# How to write the selenium code to select the random recaptcha images

Tags: java, selenium

I try with this code, but Eclipse cannot select the recaptcha images using selenium

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"recaptcha-verify-button\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of Recaptcha to be NOT automatically selectable by ANY bot? (Which includes Selenium). Simply ask your devs to provide test environment where captcha is turned off

Comment: If there is any other options for this recaptcha automation in selenium pls share here,

Comment: @Pavel Janicek
     I will try to find the code to test recaptcha in my website but I could n't find solution.I got test key in my developer.How to use that key to test recaptcha I ama not robot,

Comment: If you are indeed owner of your page, then create special copy of your pages. Here, replace recaptcha code with simple checkbox. Your goal is to test if your register process works. Not if recaptcha works. It works :) Recaptcha's deal is to stop automated scripts, like Selenium. That's why it's near impossible to come up with a solution